# Can Bitcoin mining hardware be used for other Crypto coins?

Tags: mining-hardware, asic

Can Bitcoin mining hardware be used for other Crypto coins?

Answer (score 2):

You can do, if they are using the same mining algorithm. Bitcoin is using SHA256, here is a list of other coins using the same algorithm:

[SHA256-Coins](http://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency/?sha256hr=1.00&sha256p=100.00&sha256pc=0.1000&scrypthr=1000.00&scryptp=500.00&scryptpc=0.1000&scryptnhr=450.00&scryptnp=500.00&scryptnpc=0.1000&x11hr=3000.00&x11p=500.00&x11pc=0.1000&keccakhr=500.00&keccakp=500.00&keccakpc=0.1000&quarkhr=5000.00&quarkp=500.00&quarkpc=0.1000&groestlhr=10.00&groestlp=500.00&groestlpc=0.1000&sha256c=true&scryptc=false&scryptnc=false&x11c=false&keccakc=false&quarkc=false&groestlc=false&e=Coinbase)

Other coins like Litecoin are using the Scrypt algorithm, those are not compatible with bitcoin mining hardware.